# Microsoft Script Editor for Internet Explorer on XP Home?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, windows-xp, internet-explorer-6

My understanding is that Microsoft Script Editor is the best debugging utility for IE.  To enable debugging in IE6 on XP, I found these instructions:

> ---
>
> On Windows XP SP2+, the option has been split to two:
>
> 1. Go to Tools->Internet
>      Options…->Advanced->Disable Script
>      Debugging (Internet Explorer)
> 2. Go to
>      Tools->Internet
>      Options…->Advanced->Disable Script
>      Debugging (Other)
>
> Unchecking the first will enable
>   debugging for IE.
>
> ---

Once enabled, I'm supposed to see a new menu under “View > Script debugger” to activate debugging.

Unfortunately, unchecking both check boxes and restarting my computer does reveal this new "Script debugger" option.  This worked on Windows 2000, but it fails for XP SP3.

1. Any clues on how to install MSFT Script Editor for IE6 on XP SP3?
2. Recommendations for alternatives to Script Editor for IE6?

Comment: thanks for the formatting johannes.  i didn't realize the original post looked so screwy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, redsquare.

After much experimentation, I finally discovered how to install MSE on XP SP3:

1) Disable the checkboxes as described above.

2) Open MS Excel.  Go to Tools -> Macro -> Microsoft Script Editor.  Clicking this option will prompt installation of MSE.  Install MSE.

3) Once MSE is accessible from Excel, open MSE.  Go to Debugging -> Web Debugging.  Clicking this option will prompt installation of MSE Web Debugging.  Install it.`enter code here`

Once Web Debugging is ready, restart IE, and voila!  Under the View menu, you'll now see the Script Debugger option.

Finally ...

Comment: BTW, I have wasted at least two hours trying to track down this solution ... Hopefully someone else benefits from this experience!

Comment: Visual Web Developer Express is a much smoother JS debugger for IE < 8.

Comment: The experience you get in the visual studio is also alot richer than the outdated script debugger

Answer (score 4):

You can debug with [visual web express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/). Instructions [here](http://www.berniecode.com/blog/2007/03/08/how-to-debug-javascript-with-visual-web-developer-express/)

edit: MS's site doesn't play nicely with older versions of IE. It's impossible to get the tabs to expand to get the links to the software. Use Chrome to browse the links above, or use this URL http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9730788

Answer (score 0):

The above answer may not work for those of us with Office 2007 or newer Office products.

Here is my location of the MSE7.EXE file (or do your own Windows Search for the file).

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\MSE7.EXE

Also don't forget to make sure you have the full Script Editor installed on your local computer.

CONTROL PANEL -> ADD/REMOVE PROGRAMS -> OFFICE 2007 -> CHANGE -> OFFICE TOOLS -> Script Editor -> Run All From my Computer

But I would personally go with "Visual Web Developer"